# My follower's body turns grey

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My follower's body has mismatched color.

So, I used a different kind of companion mod. This error didn't happen in one companion mod, but happened in all companion body mod.

I used CBBE body, and downloaded all the mod requirements (all follower/companion requirements).

The face didn't turn to purple, but the body turned to light grey or something. The bug happened when I changed my companion's outfit. When there's a sunlight, the body glows as well. I have all the DLCs.

Here's a screenshot of the bug / error :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if a texture file got corrupted.  Try re-importing the mods that have to do with this character.  The companion mod and  the body mods.  If your using  steam  unsubscribe  from a mod then subscribe to  it again. And ensure that all the appropriate  mods are turned on and in a correct order in the "data files" (or something like that) on the pre-start screen.